# Dark theme SO is desaturated

Tags: discussion, design, dark-mode

I noticed that Stack Overflow's UI has recently been desaturated. Maybe it's just my monitor, and in this case please correct me.

However, this change affected dark theme a little too much in my opinion, for example my beloved Stack Overflow orange color is gone (you will surely agree that the line at the top of pages is not the same as, e.g. the META part of the Meta logo), and I believe the accepted ticks are too bright. Again, this is only my opinion.

[image]
[image]
[image]

However, sometimes the text even becomes less readable, for example here, in the "linked questions" section of questions.

[image]

I think it is ok in light theme, so maybe some colors have not been double-checked for SO dark theme?

Comment: For the future: check the "all questions" page on meta first to ensure you're not posting a duplicate of a recent post. You go to that page by clicking on the top-left hamburger menu button and then choosing "questions". Why it isn't the default front page on meta, I do not know. In general it is a very safe assumption that you're not the first to complain about styling changes. We live for that sh*t.

Comment: @Gimby I see that some of my questions are duplicates, and this because I usually search my question in the search bar before posting it, but I think anyone that uses it thinks, as I do, that it is not the best search engine, maybe because one would phrase their question a different way than what has been posted before. I will try to follow your advice next time.